# Receiving data in C on a TCP server socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I've been trying to receive data on a server socket from a client with the following code,

server.c

```
int startServer(uint16_t myPort)
{
  int listenFd = 0, connfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  listenFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);
  if (listenFd == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(myPort);

  if (-1 == bind(listenFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))) {
    perror("bind");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (-1 == listen(listenFd, 10)) {
    perror("listen");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  printf("Server listening on %d\n", myPort);

  int n = 0, k;
  char recvBuff[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in conn_addr;
  unsigned int len = sizeof(conn_addr);

  while(1)
  {
     connfd = accept(listenFd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);

     n = recv(connfd, &recvBuff, 1023, 0);
     printf("Recd: %d bytes\n",n);
     for (k=0; k<16; ++k) { printf("%d: 0x%02X, ", k, recvBuff[k]); }

     sleep(1);
   }
}
```

and in client.c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd = 0, n = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("\n Usage: %s <ip of server> \n",argv[0]);
        return 1;
    } 

    if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
        return 1;
    } 

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\n inet_pton error occured\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
       printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
       return 1;
    } 

    uint32_t dataVal = 0xa0b0c0d0;
    int res = write(sockfd, (void*)&dataVal, sizeof(dataVal));
    printf("%d bytes sent\n", res);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

However with this I see the server saying it received the bytes but the line after that printing the bytes (in a for loop) doesn't ever seem to be executed. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: does adding `printf("\n");` after the for loop (or adding "\n" to the printf inside the for loop) help?

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: Hmm.. that's funny, with a \n inside the printf() the data is being output. Any explanation as to why it was not without the \n?

Comment: The `memset` call is wrong: `memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));` set the memory to the _character_ `'0'`, i.e. the value 48.

Comment: Remember that output to `stdout` is _buffered_. Printing a newline flushes the buffers which does the actual printing.

Comment: Thanks. @cegfault, if you could add this explanation as a solution would be great.

Comment: BTW: you are restricting yourself to legacy technology, not working with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: and after you are finished with `connfd` on the server side, you should `close()` it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `printf("\n");` after the for loop, or "\n" to the printf inside the for loop.

`printf` writes to `stdout`, which is buffered.  This means that output will not display until the buffer is filled, flushed, or a newline is sent.  As such, it is easiest to ensure output by sending a newline.